# compiler reports: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘using’

Tags: c++

I have two files, `homework1.cc` and `homework1.h`.

The top of `homework1.cc` is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include "homework1.h"

using namespace std;
```

and the top of in `homework1.h` is

```
#ifndef _rt_H
#define _rt_H

#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <GL/glut.h>

using namespace std;
```

This is where I use `list` in `homework1.h`

```
class surTriangle
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
    list <int> surTriangles;

    bool compareVertex(Vector3f anotherVec)
    {
        if(anotherVec[0] == x && anotherVec[1] == y && anotherVec[2] == z)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

}
```

When I attempt to compile `homework.cc`, the compiler reports

> homework1.cc:8: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘using’

However when I delete `#include <list>` or the third piece of code above it compiles successfully.

Would you please help me to find out what's the problem is?

Comment: I think you're using the term "header" incorrectly, or confusingly. Usually you call the whole `.h` file the "header"; you just mean "top of file" I think, or possibly "preamble".

Comment: g++ -o homework1 homework1.cc -lglut -lGLU -lGL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a semicolon after class declaration. (the last line of the class fragment of `homework1.h`). Otherwise using is interpreted as identifier as in

```
class X {
} x;
```

Answer (score 3):

**You forgot `;` at the end of your class definition.**

When debugging parse errors, it's useful to consider how the preprocessor works; in your mind (or with `gcc -E` if you want to actually view it properly) imagine what the code looks like after `#include` directives have been resolved.

You'd then see that the error falls directly after your class definition, which narrows things down tremendously. The error says that `using` is "unexpected", which typically indicates an issue terminating/concluding the previous statement. This leads to spotting the missing semicolon, which is a classic typo.